# SDL2, JNI and UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, java-native-interface, sdl, sdl-2, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have the following setup - a MainActivity with button which starts SDLActivity (SDL2). On the C++ side of my SDL project I have a main.cpp with declared native function:

```
extern "C"  void  Java_org_libdsl_app_SDLActivity_nativeSetAcc (JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jint Acc);

void Java_org_libdsl_app_SDLActivity_nativeSetAcc (JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jint Acc)
{
    SDL_Log ("set acc");
//  does something with the Acc value
}
```

I've put the following in the SDLActivity.java:

```
public static native void nativeSetAcc (int Acc);
```

but I'm getting unsatisified link error (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity.nativeSetAcc:(I)V)

The C/SDL side compiles OK ("jni.h" is included as well). The android part runs fine until I want to use nativeSetAcc;

The strange part is that other JNI functions from SDL library do indeed work (nativeQuit, nativeResume, etc). And I'm sure that I do LoadLibrary ("main") - the code inside main's main() is working (looping SDL events, etc).

Looking at the hexdump of libmain.so I do see the Java_org_libdsl_app_SDLActivity_nativeSetAcc string.

Please help! Surely I'm missing something small, but I can't see.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `extern "C"  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_libdsl_app_SDLActivity_nativeSetAcc (JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jint Acc);` and `void JNICALL Java_org_libdsl_app_SDLActivity_nativeSetAcc (JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jint Acc)` ?

Comment: Nope, tried that. Same thing. Thanks anyway for your effort, though.

By the way, I just need to pass the integer from MainActivity to the main.cpp side somehow. The above way (native/JNI functions) works, I use it in other projects, but here the SDL somehow messes up. I would get other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys, I'm stupid. Instead of *libsdl* I was using *libdsl* in the code. A little sleep at sunday is very recommended